# How to nest LinearLayouts within a parent RelativeLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to make a sample Calculator application in which I need to nest multiple LinearLayouts within a parent RelativeLayout, each LinearLayout consists of 2 text boxes aligned horizontally and a radio button for the operation selected, so I have radio buttons for the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. and the UI should look something like the one in the image, wherein I have 2 text fields and a radio button aligned horizontally for every operation, but I am not able to come up with an effective way to nest the LinearLayouts effectively within the RelativeLayout, some help will be appreciated.

Here is the XML file that describes the UI of the application

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_number1" 
                  android:inputType="number"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_number2" 
                  android:inputType="number"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/addition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/addition" 
            android:checked="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout1">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_number3" 
                  android:inputType="number"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_number4" 
                  android:inputType="number"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/subtraction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/subtraction" 
            android:checked="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the `layout_height` of your `LinearLayout`s to `wrap_content`?

Comment: In that case I must remove the layout_weight flag or I should remove it in that case isn't it?

Comment: `layout_weight` is on the elements *inside* the `LinearLayout`. Don't change that.  Try changing the `layout_height` of the `LinearLayout`s themselves to `wrap_content`, e. g. `<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"...>`

Comment: Ohh, man that does the job for me :D , can you explain what actually happened when I changed this?

Comment: You were telling the `LinearLayout`s to each assume the height of the parent -- the `RelativeLayout`.  The `RelativeLayout` was already the height of the entire screen, so the `LinearLayout`s both wanted to be the height of the entire screen, as well.  Obviously, that wasn't going to work out.

Comment: Nice wallpaper, BTW. ;-)

Comment: try what mharper had said.

Comment: @mharper : thanks for the wallpaper compliment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `layout_height` on each `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`.